# "Invalid index ... number is required." when trying to reference a string key in a map of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I want to create a Terraform module for dealing with a lot of DNS records in Route53 and I decided to use the `for_each` meta-argument and describe the records as a `list` of `objects`. However, to be able to work with that `list` in the `for_each` I have to convert it to a `map`, like this: `toset(keys({for key, value in var.dns_records:  key => value}))`

However, this enumerates the map keys (0 ... 9 ...) based on the order of the DNS records objects in that initial `list`.
This means that changing the order or NOT deleting/adding from the bottom will change the map keys for the records and Terraform will pick that as a change, even though only the order changed, not the content of the records.

Given this, I thought about using the DNS records names for the map's keys, so that they are unique and the order doesn't matter, but I faced another issue that I'm not sure how to avoid at this point.

*Here is the error I'm getting (note that I only left the error for the `name` field, as it repeats for the rest of the fields):*

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│   on ../../modules/multi-dns/dns.tf line 5, in module "dns":
│    5:   name = var.dns_records[each.key].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "test1"
│     │ var.dns_records is list of object with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.
╵
│ Error: Invalid index
│   on ../../modules/multi-dns/dns.tf line 5, in module "dns":
│    5:   name = var.dns_records[each.key].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "test2"
│     │ var.dns_records is list of object with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.
...
```

I've also tried referencing the values in that map in the following ways, but without success:

```
name = var.dns_records[each.key]["name"]
name = each.key.name
name = each.key["name"]
...
```

Here is how the code looks like in the various .tf files:

*modules/multi-dns/dns.tf*

```
module "dns" {
  source = "../dns"
//for_each = toset(keys({for key, value in var.dns_records:  key => value})) <- this works, but has the "order" side-effect
  for_each = toset(keys({for key, value in var.dns_records:  "${value.name}" => value}))
  name = var.dns_records[each.key].name
  type = var.dns_records[each.key].type
  records = var.dns_records[each.key].records
}
```

*modules/multi-dns/vars.tf*

```
variable "dns_records" {
  type = list(object({
    name    = string
    type    = string
    records = list(string)
  }))
}
```

*services/test/dns.tf*

```
module "dns" {
  source = "../../modules/multi-dns"

  dns_records = var.dns_records
}
```

*services/test/vars.tf*

```
variable "dns_records" {
  default = [
    {
      name = "test1"
      type = "A"
      records = [
        "1.2.3.4"
      ]
    },
    {
      name = "test2"
      type = "CNAME"
      records = [
        "example.org."
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

```
module "dns" {
  source = "../dns"

  for_each = {for key, value in var.dns_records:  "${value.name}" => value}

  name = each.value.name
  type = each.value.type
  records = each.value.records
}
```

Comment: Wow, Marcin, thank you! I'm not sure why I skipped this syntax. I was so entangled in the `toset(keys())` combo that I totally forgot about it and was pulling my hair out because I knew it should work.